# react router v6 useNavigate vs Navigate location implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

From what I understand, with the replacement of history in react router v6, the implementation of useNavigate() and Navigate should achieve similar behavior.
How could I implement the below to function similarly to achieve return to previous page before login:

useNavigate (https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#usenavigate):

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
useEffect(() => {
    return navigate(-1, { replace: true }); 
});
```

Navigate component(https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#navigate):

```
<Navigate to="/home" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you are asking how to use achieve the same behavior with the `navigate` function as the `Navigate` component to redirect back to a page a user was attempting to access prior to being redirected to authenticate.

Assuming you have implemented appropriate route protection that grabs the current location being accessed and redirects to the login route with a referrer passed in state:

```
const location = useLocation();

 ...

<Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />
```

The login component would access the state and upon a successful authentication redirect *back* to the location that was passed, or a fallback/default path like the app's home page.

```
const location = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const { from } = location.state || {};
navigate(from?.pathname || "/", { replace: true });
```